# Angular 4 - Router redirectTo using variable segment

Tags: angular, routes

In the routing Routes below, I'm receiving the following error when im trying to fetch http://localhost:4200/

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot redirect to '/:userCountry/:userLanguage/home'. Cannot find ':userCountry'.
>   Error: Cannot redirect to '/:userCountry/:userLanguage/home'. Cannot find ':userCountry'.
>       at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.findPosParam (router.es5.js:1784)

Every other routing path is working, it's only the redirectTo who seems to not substitute the value of variable userCountry (and userLanguage also).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/:userCountry/:userLanguage/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: ':userCountry/:userLanguage/home', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: ':userCountry/:userLanguage/about', loadChildren: './about/about.module#AboutModule' },
   { path: ':userCountry/:userLanguage/terms', loadChildren: './terms/terms.module#TermsModule' },
   { path: ':userCountry/:userLanguage/privacy', loadChildren: './privacy/privacy.module#PrivacyModule' },
   { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

My variables already have value when the error appends.

Here is an extract from my console.log()

```
[AppRoutingModule.constructor]this.userLanguage=fr
    [AppRoutingModule.constructor]this.userCountry=ca  
    ...  
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot redirect to '/:userCountry/:userLanguage/home'. Cannot find ':userCountry'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass default values to `userCountry` and `userLanguage` for route matching when it is in the `''` route. You can do like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/germany/ge/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: ':userCountry/:userLanguage/home', component: HomeComponent }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using a geoip service in order to assign the userCountry variable ('us' for United States, 'ca' for Canada and so on...), i cannot hardcode the userCountry value because my app show different content depending on which country the user is. The same goes for userLanguage, i dont want to show english content to french user or vice versa by hardcoding the country/language for every user who will comme to the homepage of my website, i have to dynamically assign theses values for my homepage.

Comment: So in this case you need first to load another component for the `''`, from it get the appropriate values and then redirect user to the `HomeComponent`

Comment: Hi, thank you it solved my problem. However, i dont understand why i have to use another component in order to do the redirect when in this tutorial the guy use variable directly in redirectTo https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-redirects-2826177761fc

Comment: Because you have to detect the country/language. For the `''` you redirect directly another route which wants this variables to match. In that example I don't see any redirect with given value